# Cambiar formato de YYYY/DD/MM a YYYY/MM/DD en SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Trate de realizar la siguiente consulta en *SQL Server 2008 R2* ordenando la fecha que esta en texto con el formato de `YYYY-MM-DD`.

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '2007-4-14');
```

Pero me muestra un error:

> La conversión del tipo de datos varchar en datetime produjo un valor fuera de intervalo.

Pero al usar el formato `YYYY-DD-MM` en el texto de la fecha de la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '2022-13-4');
```

Se realiza la consulta correctamente, no soy experto en SQL pero creí que el formato era `YYYY-MM-DD`, alguien me puede explicar que esta sucediendo o si esto es normal y si no es normal como puedo cambiar el formato, por favor ayuda.

Comment: Bienvenido Axl a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Corre `DBCC USEROPTIONS;` y revisa la propiedad `dateformat` ¿Qué es lo que dice?

Comment: La columna puede ser varchar pero debe estar en formato YYYY-MM-DD, de lo contrario no podrás usarla para hacer consultas de rangos ya que rompe la lógica de comparación de fechas tipo string. Si la columna es tipo varchar, y está en otro formato, sugiero convertir los valores a YYYY-MM-DD y se resolverán todos tus problemas. Obviamente la aplicación también debe alterarse para que inserte los valores nuevos en ese formato.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho Corri `DBCC USEROPTIONS;` y en la propiedad `dateformat` dice `dmy`